# Safari gives HTML element negative height?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, height, element

Somehow Safari gives my button or/and input submit elements a negative hieght of 20px and I can't figure out why.

The exact same code works perfectly fine on Firefox and Chrome.

All of the elements you see are created by javascript and placed inside the DOM.

[image]

Comment: Hello, how did you fixed this issue?

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I still didn't. The project is unfortunately not online yet.. So if you find a solution I would love to hear it !